# 18.04 LTS System Load Indicator

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell

When I run System Load Indicator, I only see a single bit of the graphic in the upper right corner of the new GNOME shell. Image:

[image: emphasized text]

That little white line to the left of the network icon is all the the system load indicator shows.

This is a brand-new install of 18.04, Intel Core i5, 24Gb ram, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 graphics card. Lots of free disk space.